# Wordpress wp_get_current_user() does not work anymore

Tags: php, wordpress

I used for this months this code on some pages I developed in PHP attached to my Wordpress website.

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../wp-load.php' );
require __DIR__ . '/../Connection.php';
include('config.php');

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if (! $current_user->exists() ) {
    header("location: " . LOGIN_URL);
}
.... more
```

But today the script does not work anymore, because it does not retrieve the current user.

My version of wordpress is 5.2.3

What can I do? Thanks

NEWS:

Other function and variables from Wordpress work, like $product, so the inclusion of the file is correct.
Maybe it's a problem of cookies and sessions?

Comment: Try post result of $current_user after var_dump?

Comment: object(WP_User)#10736 (8) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#11267 (0) { } ["ID"]=> int(0) ["caps"]=> array(0) { } ["cap_key"]=> NULL ["roles"]=> array(0) { } ["allcaps"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> NULL ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not logged in (properly). Yes, logged in means the browser can provide a valid cookie corresponding to a user account. You can also check `is_user_logged_in()` before `wp_get_current_user()`.

Comment: Also is_user_logged_in() does not work, even if I'm correctly logged in the website :(